# How to call different methods for different current pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
perPage: 3,
  currentPage: 1,

  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.productsList.length
    },

    methods: {

      page() {
        if (this.currentPage = 2) {
          let accToken = localStorage && localStorage.loggedinUser ? localStorage.loggedinUser : null;
          const categoryUrl = project_key + '/product-projections/search?offset=12&limit=12';

          const sendGetRequest = async() => {

            let access_token = await axios.request({
              method: "get",
              baseURL: categoryUrl,
              headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + accToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              data: {}
            }).then((response) => {
              if (response) {
                // this.productsList = response.body;
                this.productsList = response.data.results;
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                console.log(this.productsList);
              }

            });




          };
          sendGetRequest();
        }

      },
```

```html
<b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" aria-controls="my-table" @change="page"></b-pagination>
<p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>
```

I am using b-pagination event per-page="perPage", And i am writing method to call api.

Where in perPage() i am calling  if (this.currentPage = 2) {}. So my question is by using single :per-page="perPage", can i write multiple methods and change currentPage for each method?

Comment: Do you want to call different methods for different current pages?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari yes exactly, But not sure how to call method for each page. and the written method  for each page should not override the other method.

Comment: Yes when the current page matches with page1(one method) when matches with page2(another method).......

Answer (score 0):

```
<b-pagination 
    v-model="currentPage" 
    :total-rows="rows" 
    :per-page="perPage" 
    aria-controls="my-table" 
    @change="page"
></b-pagination>
```

If you look into the code. There is @change event is listening. You need to add page() function in your methods. like below

```
methods: {
    page(event) {
        this.currentPage = event
        let offset = (this.currentPage * this.perPage)
        const categoryUrl = project_key + `/product-projections/search?offset=${offset}&limit=${this.perPage}`;
        // other logics....
    }
}
```

Comment: here offset is currentPage * this.perPage. So in my case  have products which need to show like in page1 offset0 limit 12, and page2 offset12 , limit12 and page3 offset24 , limit 12. So how can i divide accordingly

Comment: your offset need to do some calculation based on current page. I had show it in the code. Try it out

Comment: I tried it, but when calculating offset, in the data I have given perpage as 3,  and current page is 1, So when calculating above current page * perpage giving as wrong offset value. Like offset6 and limit 3?

Comment: So for second page do I need to use if else statement to loop the api call for per page  or all 4 pages in if else if statement do I need to write?

Comment: No if else statement needed. Just calculate the offset and limit and send to your Api